# pcall a GetUserIdFromNameAsync()

Tags: lua, roblox

Ok so im making a follow friend GUI thing and im trying to use GetUserIdFromNameAsync from a string with a name in it. And im trying to pcall so i dont get errors but it returns nil even when its a name that i know works because i call for it regularly above. and it returns the id in the print but when i try to pcall then use an if it comes back nil everytime and goes to my else statement.

```
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")

script.Parent.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player, id)
    place = player.GuiFolder
    print(game.Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(id))
    --ISSUE IN LINE BELOW-- ISSUE IS IN THE LINE BELOW
    friend, msg = pcall(game.Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(id))
    if friend then
    print(player.Name, player, player.PlayerGui.MainMenu.Name)
    if player:IsFriendsWith(friend) then
        place.IsFriend.Value = true
        local success, errorMsg, placeId, instanceId = TeleportService:GetPlayerPlaceInstanceAsync(friend)
            if success then
                place.foundplayerbar.Value = "Found player. Would you like to join?"
                place.Activated.Value = true
            else enter code here
                place.errorbar.Value = "ERROR: Player not online!"
            end
        else place.errorbar.Value = "ERROR: Not Friends with person!"
    end
    else place.errorbar.Value = "ERROR: Player doesn't exist!"
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the "Programming in Lua" ebook: "Suppose you want to run a piece of Lua code and to catch any error raised while running that code. Your first step is to encapsulate that piece of code in a function... The pcall function calls its first argument in protected mode, so that it catches any errors while the function is running. If there are no errors, pcall returns true, plus any values returned by the call. Otherwise, it returns false, plus the error message."

Instead of calling pcall on the function directly, encapsulate everything in a function first:

```
function func()
    friend, msg = game.Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(id)
    if friend then
        ...
    else
        ...
    end
 end
```

Then you can call the function with pcall and catch any errors:

```
local status, err = pcall(func)
if not status then print(err) end
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Lua documentation:

> Suppose you want to run a piece of Lua code and to catch any error
>   raised while running that code. Your first step is to encapsulate that
>   piece of code in a function; let us call it `foo`... then, **you call foo with pcall**...

Your code uses pcall with a function, but it calls the function rather than using it as an argument.

To fix this, you could put `game.Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(id)` in a function and use it as the argument, but an easier way is to use an anonymous function, like

```
 friend, msg = pcall(function() 
     game.Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync(id) 
 end)
```

which will give you the proper value.